# Is TCP output queue blocking keep alive?

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, keep-alive

I have the following situation:
A TCP connection is established. The client (with linux running) has keep-alive activated and it works as required.

The problem is now: When I unplug the ethernet cable on the client side between a request from the server and the answer from the client, the keep-alive stops working.

I see from netstat that the Send-Q is filled. Is the send-q related to the TCP keep-alive? Is there a way to clear this queue?

Regards,
Frogtime

Comment: Define 'stops working'.

Answer (score 0):

TCP keep-alive is just a fancy way of saying "send 0 bytes packets to keep a connection alive, if there's no data". Since you're still sending headers, and the other side still has to ACK it, at IP level you're still communicating, but not at socket level.

Obviously unpluggint stops the IP packets and the keep-alive. Also, as long as there's a send-Q, there's no point in sending empty keep-alive packets, so they are obviously related - inversely. Keep-alive packets are created when the queue is empty.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I thought. Is there a way to empty the send-Q?

Comment: @Frogtime: As in, "unsending" the data?

Comment: Yes. For example: If the send-q size hasn't change for a while "unsent" the data so TCP keep alive is working again.

Comment: @Frogtime: That doesn't make sense. Stop thinking of keep-alive as magic, and read what I wrote. **Since there is TCP data, there is no point in sending empty TCP packets aka keep-alive**

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The point is: The client never closes its socket because it doesn't know that the connection is gone on a lower level. Is the only way to close the socket, to close it manually when the link is down? I was trying to solve this problem on the TCP layer itself.

Comment: @Frogtime: That's rather relevant information - just close the socket then. There's no way to do that automatically as there is no obvious way to say for sure a link is permanently gone.

Comment: Thanks. Then I have to do it this way.